# How to change background color when list is loading in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, wifi

Sorry for mistakes in language.

In my project i scanned all the available wifi network's ssid and i have listed it. same time i am having sqlite db,in that db i am storing the netwotk's ssid. if i click a network from the list it validate the selected ssid with the ssid that stored in db, if it is same the backround color becomes blue to that particular ssid in the list.here i am using the onitemclicklistener.

how can i validate the list items while the list page is loading and change the background color to blue without using the onitemclicklistener.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbhelper=new SdtDBHelper(this);
    listv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    wifiManager.startScan();
}

protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
    WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}

class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
            /*String ssid = wifiScanList.get(i).SSID;*/
            wifis[i] = (( wifiScanList.get(i).SSID));
        }

        listv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wifis));

        listv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long id) {

                TextView temp=(TextView) view;
                String wifi_id=temp.getText().toString();
                String networkSSID = wifi_id;

                dbhelper.open();
                dbhelper.CreateWifiEntry();
                dbhelper.getAllWifi();
                Cursor cursor=dbhelper.getAllWifi();

                if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
                    // start activity a
                    if(dbhelper.validatewifi(wifi_id)){
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                    else{
                        /*dbhelper.CreateWifiEntry();*/
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry Created..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you are asking need to show blue background for list item in first time loading itself right. pls you custom adapter and do this id validation function within getview of your custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Arraylist` corresponding to the wifis....
after you get the list of wifis , hit query in database to get the availability of the ssid in the db. 
If it is present, `arraylist.get(position) = true`, else leave it.

Then

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter/ArrayAdapter{    
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (arraylist.get(position)){
        //set Background color here, something like below
        row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i pass my array list into base adapter?